# Dynamic nested lists in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that has a nested data model:

A quote has 1 to many quoteitems.

A quoteitem has 1 to many quotelineitems.

A user can dynamically (using JQuery) add or remove a new quoteitem from a quote, and can dynamically add or remove quotelineitems from a quoteitem. all on a single page.

This is proving remarkably difficult to do in ASP.NET, the most comprehensive example I can find is this one from 2011 - http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/.  Is this still the best way of achieving what I'm trying to do, or have changes in the newer versions of ASP.NET opened up a different way?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: No, you still need a plugin like that, or if you want a client side solution without the ajax calls, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wqE6Rb)

Comment: That DotNetFiddle seems to do exactly what I want, and seems a much easier solution.  Does it bind to the viewmodel on postback?  And does validation work?

Comment: Yes it will bind and validation will work (but you need to ensure you add the correct `data-val` attributes - and the easy way to do that is to create a temporary nested `for` loops to display each of the objects (a `quote` containing a `quoteitem` containing a `quotelineitem`) and inspect the html it generates. While this is obviously much faster that making ajax calls, it does mean more maintenance - any time you change a property name, or a validation attribute, you then need to update the templates

Comment: Are you able to give me an example with the data-val attributes as an answer so I can mark this question complete?